# Questions about Customs/Insurance/Transport for your equipment?

Tags: production

Sorry if it's not the right forum for such a question but is it possible to get any feedback from experimented filmmakers on how they transport their equipement abroad ?

1. For example, how do you handle customs ? Do you have like any specific document that allow you to get your equipement "anywhere" ? I'm talking about the case where you have 100 kg ~ 200 kg or more of equipement.
2. Which insurance do you have to protect the equipement from any baggage loss from the airline company (preferably a french or european insurance company) ? Some airline companies don't theoretically allow electronic equipement transport and hence in case of any loss, they refuse to refund. They allow it in practice but if they lose your luggage, they don't refund anything under the pretext of transporting electronics is not allowed.
3. How do you handle the nightmare of transporting the batteries ? We had once a shooting in a remote area in Asia without electricity. We got some solar panels but we were unable to transport the batteries or big power banks. We couldn't even send them separately. FedEx, DHL, UPS all refused to transport them saying it' considered as dangerous good.

Any feedback is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Which country are you based in, and where do you plan to go?

Comment: We are based in France and have several projects in Africa and Asia (Tanzania, Kenya, Mongolia, Vietnam)

Comment: Regarding customs: Maybe the ATA Carnet helps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_Carnet (France and Mongolia are accepting it).

Answer (score 3):

I can only write from the experience of travelling from the UK to many other countries with kit a few years ago (pre-covid era):

In the UK, if you provide an equipment list to the airport customs desk before you leave, they will examine it, take a copy and stamp it.  The form is called a [Returned Goods Relief Form](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/import-and-export-returned-goods-relief-declarations-for-using-duplicate-lists-ce1246).  This is to prove that you are taking valuable equipment out of the country for filming purposes, and plan to return with it (not sell it overseas and avoid paying taxes).

The list needs to show every item of equipment you are carrying and should have columns for: Manufacturer, Manufacturers Model, Serial Number, Value (£).

Print many copies of the equipment list, so that any official who demands one can take one.

Put a copy of each equipment list in each bag, Put a "lost luggage" note in each suitcase in the local language, and English.

Customs in the incoming country is another issue.  It depends on the country.  Research it carefully. Some countries need you to buy a "carnet".

Make sure no bag weighs more that the allowed limit by the airline.

With regards to batteries, the correct procedure a few years ago was to inform the airline that you would be carrying batteries. Make sure the weight of the batteries did not exceed their rules.  If they are Lithium Polymer (LiPo) batteries (often used in drones), carry them in LiPo bags which should reduce fire risk if they malfunction on the journey. Any exposed terminals should be taped over.

The airlines usually (and correctly) state that you should carry the batteries in hand luggage, so if they do malfunction, it would quickly become apparent - if they were in the hold, it would be too late to do anything.  Security guards in airports often aren't aware of this rule, and may try to get you to put batteries in the hold.  Allow time for this when you travel.

Officials love letters. Get a letter from the airline confirming that you can travel with the batteries. Take a letter from your employer confirming that you will be filming in x country for y days and address it "to whom it may concern".  Print many copies on headed paper.

Can't comment on insurance as it was handled by the company I worked for.  Large broadcasters usually have insurance, but often the excess is so high it is effectively useless. More important is the third party liability insurance, in case you injure somebody else during your work.

Also - use Peli cases. They're waterproof, fairly indestructible, and if they do get broken, [they will offer you a replacement](https://peliproducts.co.uk/info/returns#claim).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :)